# Какой тип в C# обеспечивает точное представление значения с плавающей точкой

Tags: c#, float

Какой тип обеспечивает точное представление значения с плавающей точкой (float)?

Comment: А **что** такое «точное представление»? Формализуйте. Иначе точный ответ дать невозможно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Точное представление в C# обеспечивает тип [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/364x0z75.aspx) - 28–29 значащих цифр.

Абсолютно точного представления числа с плавающей точкой в C# нет, т.к. оно потребовало бы бесконечного количества памяти (по крайней мере для иррациональных чисел).

Answer (score 3):

В C# нет такого типа. Все типы имеют ограниченную точность, кроме класса [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.biginteger).
Последний можно приспособить для хранения чисел с плавающей точкой, если отдельно хранить еще и положение десятичной точки в числе.

Однако, смею заметить, что даже не все непериодические десятичные числа обеспечивают точное представление. Так, например, число `1/3` не может иметь точного представления в виде непериодической десятичной дроби.

Answer (score 0):

Тип **decimal**. В отличии от **double** он хранится в десятичном виде, поэтому не имеет ошибок округления... Но из его минусов меньший диапазон значений

Answer (score 0):

Тип decimal, часто используется в банковских операциях, имеет наибольшее кол-во чисел после запятой(после BigInteger как указал @Dmitry)
ссылка на пример
https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEcj0r